# Python - Library not found when running code as sudo

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo, libpcap

I'm trying to use the [python binding for the libpcap C library](https://github.com/karpierz/libpcap) and when I run the code as sudo or root, a message is returned saying that libpcap was not found:

> import libpcap as pcap
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libpcap'

But running without sudo works. The problem with this is that some library functions need super user privilege. Has anyone ever seen something like this? I appreciate any tips.

Comment: yes all you have to do is install the necessary packages as sudo.  so `sudo pip install ...`  Each account can have it's own version of pip and it's own library of packages

Comment: I did this as sudo. The documentation doesn't specify but I cloned the repository and did sudo python -m pip install ./libpcap, but it didn't work.

Comment: the library doesn't already exist in PyPi?

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: It says it is on their github page this is how you install it `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade libpcap`

Comment: Output of `pip show libpcap` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the required packages, but with sudo. Like `sudo pip install ...`

That should fix it.

Comment: It didn't work, as I said in the comment above, I did this and it didn't work.

Comment: Running `pip install` with elevated privileges is virtually _never_ the right solution.